# After building docker image my javascript is not working in my nuxt app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuxt.js

I used the shell script to build docker image and my javascript is not working anymore but when i run it without docker it's working but and i' m trying to figure out why this weird behavior because there is not error on my docker and even not in my nuxt app
here are some of my files.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.4-alpine


WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && \
    apk add alpine-sdk && \
    apk add python3


RUN node -v
RUN npm -v


ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["/bin/ash"]
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
       - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./nttlab:/app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - ntt_platform


networks:
  ntt_platform:
    external: true
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the command to start your app. Something like `command: npm run serve` (or however you start Nuxt apps)

Comment: thank you for answering  but there is not problem on my docker i found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there was a warning on my terminal saying that my index file was big and the asset limit did not read the javascript so I had to extend the space on my `nuxt.config` file as follows:

```
build: {
/* Extend webpack config */
    extend (config, ctx) {
      config.performance.maxAssetSize = 700 * 1024
    }
}
```

After adding this I restarted my nuxt app and all the javascript started to work.